# Git workflow for web development

Tags: git, web, workflow

I have been playing around with git on my local machine and everything makes sense until it comes to a remote and multiple developers I start getting confused.

My goal is to have a "semi public" dev site/s that a group of 4 people can work on and push changes to the live site as they are ready. We need the dev site/s to be on the public web server so that we can get approvals before pushing changes live. Security isn't a huge concern so I am planning on just using a simple .htaccess to restrict access. Not all of the changes need to be approved but I want the dev site/s to stay up to date.

The big challenge is that 2 of the 4 of us are designers and so the whole process of making a change and pushing it live needs to be fast and simple. They are used to just ftping changes to the site. I don't want to make a 10 step process to do what they are doing with a keyboard shortcut right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Capistrano is not necessarily exclusive to Ruby on Rails; it may be configured to work with other projects. Google something along the lines of "Capistrano for PHP" to get started. There are also Ruby Gems such as railsless-deploy that will automatically configure Capistrano accordingly. On a side note... this is in response to a comment to another answer above. Sorry to do it this way but I can't yet post comments. I hope you'll all forgive me as I thought this information was worth sharing. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out:

- [Git for designers](http://github.com/blog/392-intro-to-git-for-designers)
- [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/), a graphical Git tool for OS X
- [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for deployment

This should get everyone familiar with using git and give you a tool for efficiently pushing out changes.

Comment: So to use GitX everyone would need a local copy of the entire site? I would like to avoid this if possible. We have a directory with 4Gb of PDFs that rarely change.

Comment: Unfortunately, Git (regardless of whether you use GitX or not) does not support partial checkouts.  This may be in the works.  The answer you would hear for now is that your 4Gb of PDFs should not be checked in to the (same) repository.

Comment: We have been using git for a few months now and its working great. Every user has XAMPP and a full copy of the site. We then have a server in our office that we all push and pull from. It has a post update script that uploads the changes to the master branch to web server. We use other branches for our dev servers. Its not perfect but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Before going further, I'll state quite clearly that git is **not** a web deployment tool.  Capistrano and friends are the superior solution, and mandatory for complex systems.  However, if you have a simple enough site and don't care about atomic deployments, dependencies, forced process (ensuring all changes were QAed, etc), and the like, you can sometimes get away with a post-receive hook which does a forced git checkout.  Then the process of deploying to a website would be to push to a special repository.  You could either have one repository for QA and one for production, or have the hook check the branch being pushed to and figure it which to update that way.

See http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto for more information on a simple post-receive hook for automatic checkout.

Of course, you can also have the post-receive hook call an actual web deployment system to take care of some of the problems mentioned above.

Comment: We don't have a review process for content changes so those changes are just made on the master branch. Everything else gets its own branch and is merged into master for release. We have several of those feature branches checked out on VMs in our office for review as projects progress. Its not perfect but it works well. I'll look into Capistrano, but it sounds like overkill for what we need.

Comment: Looks like Capistrano is a Ruby on Rails specific solution so it wont help unless you use Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I assumed that you had solved the problem, err, several years ago.  I was just commenting for others looking into the same problem.  If you have constraints not mentioned so that neither of the two solutions works please elucidate.  Also, please upvote if this post was useful.