# Web Development Workflow Advice

Tags: git, deployment, hosting

I’ve been doing web development for some time now but getting more serious about it these days. Currently I’m coding on a OS X 10.6 machine running PHP, MySQL, Ruby, and Apache, then uploading files through FTP to the web.

I am aware that this is not the best way to proceed as there is no versioning (SVN or Git) and no staging on the server side. However, I’m having a hard time finding something that would explain the philosophy, best practices, and approaches to setting up an environment like that.

Where can I find a nice, thorough tutorial or article that would address both the thinking behind such things as well as the technical how-to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473340/git-workflow-for-web-development contains some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is titled "Git for Designers", I find it's a helpful intro to git and the reasoning behind using a versioning system: http://thinkvitamin.com/design/git-for-designers-part-1/

Comment: Thanks, this should do to start, although it’d be cool to have a resource where developers post their workflows, something like http://usesthis.com/, but for web development specifically.